# Component camel-jsonpath gives error after adding to pom file

Tags: apache-camel, osgi

In a clean Camel project I add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
  <version>2.16.1</version>       
</dependency>
```

When I run the project I get the below error. If I remove that dependency it works. I have tried this on two different projects and the same happens. Anything else that has to be added to the pom for jsonpath to work? It seems to complain for ASM?

```
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator starting
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator started
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintContainerImpl         INFO  Bundle INT001_GetPostcodeDataFromXXX/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]
EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch.
EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch.
EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch.
EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch.
EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch.
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Service factory exception: org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:246)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:178)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:323)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSRBundleContext.getService(PojoSRBundleContext.java:162)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.namespace.NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl.addingService(NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl.java:113)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:894)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:852)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:775)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:594)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSR$1.serviceChanged(PojoSR.java:78)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:130)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSRBundleContext.registerService(PojoSRBundleContext.java:101)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.registerService(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:453)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.register(ServiceRecipe.java:193)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.registerServices(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:704)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:379)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.interfaces.ProxyClassLoader.createProxyClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:146)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.interfaces.InterfaceProxyGenerator.getProxyInstance(InterfaceProxyGenerator.java:95)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AsmProxyManager.createNewProxy(AsmProxyManager.java:80)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:53)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe$TriggerServiceFactory.getService(ServiceRecipe.java:569)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:242)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 49 more
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Service factory exception: org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:246)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:178)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:323)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSRBundleContext.getService(PojoSRBundleContext.java:162)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.namespace.NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl.addingService(NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl.java:113)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:894)
        at org.apache.felix.connect.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:852)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter
```

Edit:
After adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

It worked but doubt this is the correct way. The camel-component should get all the dependent jars.

Answer (score 5):

I posted this on the Camel nabble forum and indeed it seems you  need to add the asm dependency to get it to work.

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Error-with-Camel-component-camel-jsonpath-td5777201.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

the pom.xml are about compile-time dependencies. You have a runtime error about a missing dependency (org.objectweb.asm). You should add it to your container.

In your stack traces : a new service is registered in a blueprint context. this service is then injected in another blueprint context. for this service, the blueprint container want to wrap it in a new proxy, and to create this kind of proxy, aries blueprint need org.objectweb.asm. i don't think this error is directly related to camel-jsonpath.

Comment: Yeah, but technically the only thing I need to do is to add that dependency to use it. At least according to the documentation. http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath.html . It is strange error though, and one that does not occur if I remove that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, back when `asm-commons` with version 5.0.3 was used, I was still getting some error. As an altetrnative to previous answer, `asm-all` artifact can be used instead, since it includes other dependencies that in my scenario were breaking otherwise.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, regarding deployment, it seems quite impossible to integrate the project using this dependency to Fabric8 (no errors on console log and containers do not start), so not sure if there is a better alternative with a sort of camel-jsonpath feature.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: EDIT: the error I had referred to above was due to the lack of the XOM dependency required by camel-xmljson. The main reason why I used asm-all is that we are released from choosing its version, since it is managed by Fuse's BOM.