# apache camel camel-blueprint conflict with camel-cxf in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-camel

I try to execute a route camel create with Blueprint in Eclipse with the camel:run.
I used the archetype camel-archetype-blueprint, I make a easy blueprint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
<route id="timerToLog">
  <from uri="timer:foo?period=5000"/>
  <log message="The message contains ${body}"/>
</route>
```

In eclipse when I launch the command maven mvn camel:run, the route start, its perfect.

But when I edit the pom.xml and I add a dependency to camel-cxf, if I launch the camel:run, there is a error.

```
Unable to start bundle: 14
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:85)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.createBundleContext(Main.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.doStart(Main.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:351)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.main(Main.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/service/log/LogService
    at org.apache.geronimo.mail.Activator.start(Activator.java:52)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:132)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.log.LogService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 21 more
```

and

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.interfaces.InterfaceProxyGenerator has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:115)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:933)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:155)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.processProcessors(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.interfaces.InterfaceProxyGenerator has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AsmProxyManager.createNewProxy(AsmProxyManager.java:72)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:75)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:40)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.createProxy(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:306)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:99)
    ... 28 more
[         Blueprint Extender: 2] BlueprintContainerImpl         ERROR Unable to start blueprint container for bundle archetypeBlueprint
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/apache/aries/proxy/impl/interfaces/InterfaceProxyGenerator
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:115)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:145)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getComponentInstance(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:746)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelDependenciesFinder.process(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:863)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.processProcessors(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:515)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/apache/aries/proxy/impl/interfaces/InterfaceProxyGenerator
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AsmProxyManager.createNewProxy(AsmProxyManager.java:72)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:75)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:40)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.createProxy(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:306)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:99)
    ... 22 more
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.edu.acdijon.ses.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>archetypeBlueprint</artifactId>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Camel Blueprint Route</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <camel-version>2.13.2</camel-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>archetypeBlueprint</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Private-Package>fr.edu.acdijon.ses.demo.archetypeBlueprint.*</Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

       <!-- to run the example using mvn camel:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Can you help me to solve this error? please

### Edit

duplicate with [Component camel-jsonpath gives error after adding to pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176594/component-camel-jsonpath-gives-error-after-adding-to-pom-file)?

Answer (score 3):

I updated version of camel and added this dependencies in pom :

```
<!-- need this dependencies for the cmd camel:run -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of Camel are you using now?